# Bootstrap popover show/hide on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a Bootstrap popover on a select box. If I change the value of the select, the popover hides or shows.

- Why does the select trigger the popover?
- Is this the expected behavior?
- How can I prevent this and show/hide the popover independently the state of the select.

**HTML**:

```html
<select>
  <option>012</option>
  <option>345</option>
  <option>678</option>
  <option>910</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('select').popover({
  title: 'Error',
  content: 'Error message'
});
```

Here's an [**example in JsBin**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rugozehedu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is expected. Popovers trigger on an element click, so clicking any part of the select will show/hide the popover.

Comment: When you click on the select Element it's still on because you are stil on, but the options of the select are in fact different elements.

That could be "solved" (this is not a bug) by editing the popover source.

So you have to move the discussion in plugins repo in github.

Comment: What *do* you want to indicate whether or not the popup should be open.

Comment: @VassilisPits, Bootstrap is an incredibly extensible framework.  There's no reason to submit a bug/feature because something doesn't happen out of the box.  As long as the tooling is there to enhance it, you should feel comfortable as a web developer to do so.

Comment: @KyleMit that's not what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the [popover events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) to control when it's visible.

If you don't want the popup to ever close, that's really simple; just return false on the hide event like this:

```js
$('#myPopover').on("hide.bs.popover", function() {
  return false;
});
```

However, you probably want it to close *eventually*.  So I'd recommend closing it conditionally when the control no longer has focus.  When the controls attempts to hide, if the control still has focus, then prevent it from hiding.

Then, since you already handled the close event, you'll have to re-fire the close event later on during the element's blur event like this:

```js
$('#myPopover').on({
  "hide.bs.popover": function() {
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) return false;
  },
  "blur": function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
  }
});
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets.

```js
$('#myPopover').popover({
  title: 'Custom Message',
  content: 'Something to look at while selecting'
}).on({
  "hide.bs.popover": function() {
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) return false;
  },
  "blur": function() {
    $(this).popover('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <select id="myPopover">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>

</div>
```